# Finding team indicator from employee and manager mapping using panda

Tags: pandas

I have a people manager report where each employee is tagged to a manager.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':list(range(1,10)),
                   'SUP_ID':[100,100,100,101,100,101,101,102,102]})
```

The objective is to find the teams to which each employee belong. Employees having the same manager/supervisor ID should ideally be in the same team.

Output expected is such:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':list(range(1,10)),
                   'SUP_ID':[100,100,100,101,100,101,101,102,102],
                   'TEAM':[1,1,1,2,1,2,2,3,3]})
```

For about 50K records, what is an optimal way?

Comment: As per the suggested duplicate, `df['TEAM'] = df.groupby('SUP_ID').ngroup().add(1)` or `df['TEAM'] = pd.factorize(df.SUP_ID)[0] + 1`.